# My angular templates aren't compiling correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular-UI bootstrap for my app, and unfortunately the tooltip directive will not take a template and compile it correctly.

I am using this markup inside an ng-repeat to render search results. I would ideally prefer to do this:

```
<span class="list-group-item-actions col-md-2">
  <span class="information-container"
        tooltip-html-unsafe="{{ $templateCache.get('path/to/template.html') }}"
        tooltip-placement="left">
  </span>
</span>
```

But the directive will not execute the .get, so I resorted to adding the template directly on the model so that I could render it like so:

```
<span class="list-group-item-actions col-md-2">
  <span class="information-container"
        tooltip-html-unsafe="{{ result.tooltip }}"
        tooltip-placement="left">
  </span>
</span>
```

Inside my directive that handles the searching, I am trying to compile the template like this:

```
_.each(search_results, function(result) {
    var templScope = $scope.$new(true);
    templScope.result = result;
    result.tooltip = $compile($templateCache.get($scope.tooltip_template))(templScope).html();
});
```

This is close, as it renders the template I want, but it doesn't actually execute any of the directives or expressions that are in the template. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Not the prettiest, but it certainly works. The issue is that I wasn't applying the new DOM element, and so angular wasn't actually getting to execute the expressions or directives. What I ended up doing was this:

```
_.each(res, function(item) {
    var templScope = $scope.$new();
    templScope.item = item;
    templScope.tooltip = $compile($templateCache.get($scope.tooltip_template))(templScope);
    _.defer(function() {
        templScope.$apply();
        item.tooltip = templScope.tooltip.html();
    });
});
```

Two things worth noting

- You can't call html() before running $apply(), as the template hasn't actually been compiled with the expressions being evaluated
- I had to use _.defer() to allow the $apply() to be called on the next lifecycle, otherwise it was being called during an existing digest lifecycle